# MPI basics program

Tags: c, windows, mpi, parallel-processing, openmpi

Hi I wanted to learn using MPI in C. I am using Codeblocks on Windows 7

I ran this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int err;
   err = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   printf("Hello world!\n");
   err = MPI_Finalize();
}
```

but for some reason, i get an error at "mpi.h". Is there a way to add the library?

Comment: What error do you get? Do you know if you need to install some MPI support libraries on your platform?

Comment: the error is: mpi.h: No such file or directory

Comment: If you have already installed an MPI implementation (e.g. MPICH) then you will need to add the directory containing its include files to the list of places the compiler looks.  If you're running the compiler from the command line that would almost certainly mean using the `-I` option; if you're using an IDE, look for an "Include directories" setting.

Comment: I havent installed an MPI implementation yet.

Comment: then you need to install MPI to use mpi.h in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, install an implementation of MPI.  In the past I've used MPICH, but there are other implementations available.  I know another is LAM/MPI.  Check out the Wikipedia page for additional information at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface#Implementations

After you install MPI, use the sample code provided in the Wikipedia article to get comfortable.

Good luck!

Al